# Aproximation Property: Problm 1.e.9 in Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The open Problem 1.e.9 in Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri states:

*Let $X$ be a Banach space such that every compact $T:X\to X$ is a limit in norm of finite rank operators from $X$ into itself. Does $X$ have the A.P.?*

I understand how this statement is stronger than the implication (v)$\Rightarrow$ (i) in Theorem 1.e.4, however I had the impression for a long time that 1.e.9 is the definition of A.P., that is the norm closure of finite rank operators are the compact operators. What am I missing here?

Comment: 1.e.1 in LT I gives the definition: $X$ has AP if, for every compact set $K$ in $X$ and every $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite rank operator $T:X\rightarrow X$ so that $\Vert Tx-x\Vert\le \epsilon$ for all $x\in K$. You could also, of course, take 1.e.4 (v) to be the definition. According to Casazza's article in the Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces, Vol. I, Problem 1.e.9 is unresolved (this was published in 2001).